# Transfer values multiple text inputs to table view, add table view items as NSManaged Objects

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am just getting started with obj-c programming and cocoa. 
Here is what I am trying to accomplish and have gotten stumped on.

I have a single table view of managed objects in Window1. I have a "Add Items" button that calls Window2 that has another blank table view (AddItemsTableView) and a series of form fields a user could fill in.

When a user fills in these fields and clicks an add button in Window2, the string values of said fields are input into AddItemsTableView to show a running list of items they are preparing to add. When the finally commit the add, I would like that running list to instantiate as NSManagedObjects

Do I need to do this as a seperate entity within coredata created just for objects to be added, then transfer the objects to the new entity upon the add action? Do I need to save them in a mutable dictionary and convert the dictionary to managed objects?

It's important that the addItemsTableView only contains data for the time period the window is open. When Add is commmited, the window closes and the table bound to the core data entity in Window1 updates with new results. If Add Items in Window 1 is pressed again, Window2 is called with an empty tableview again.

I've been searching through SO and other forums for days trying to find someone attempting to do the same thing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your add table view to the original table view via a delegate `@protocol` so it can inform the other on its state and enable it to react accordingly.

Of course you use the same type of managed object throughout, no interim objects such as dictionaries. When the added data is saved, you could send the object back to the original table to be processed.

(Alternatively you can save and rely on e.g. the fetched results controller delegate - but maybe that is too advanced at this stage.)